# App Crashing as *** Assertion failure in +[SVGKImage imageWithSource:]

Tags: ios, swift, image, svgkit

I am working with SVGKit in swift Project. I properly imported SVGKit Framework and 3rd party resources folder into my project by following (https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit).

I created a folder with sets of .svg images inside the project and i am using the following code to load image into testIcon(ImageView).

```
let lockImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(named: "LockIcon.svg")
let lockImageLocal: UIImage = lockImage.uiImage
testIcon.image = lockImageLocal
```

But i am receiving the following error,

> ** Assertion failure in +[SVGKImage imageWithSource:], /Users/fss/Downloads/SVGKit-
>   2.x/Source/SVGKImage.m:229
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: newSource != nil'

Please let me know how to mention path of `.svg` image(which is inside my project) to SVGKImage image class or how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove `.svg` from image name. This method `named:` doesn't need extension.

Or you can try this way too...

**Swift 4**

```
if let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imageName", ofType: "svg")     
{
  let lockImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
  let lockImageLocal: UIImage = lockImage.uiImage
  testIcon.image = lockImageLocal
}
```

**Obj-c type**

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSBundle mainBundle][ pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"svg"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```